# Django ORM - Please check this multiple table relationship query I'm not sure what I am missing here

Tags: python, django, orm

Hi there please check the below ORM query and I'm new for ORM,

I'm getting this error,
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `name` on serializer `HospitalsSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `QuerySet` instance.
Original exception text was: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'name'.

```
hospitals = [Hospitals.objects.filter(site_id=_otl.site_id) for _otl in OTL.objects.filter(salesEmail=sales_person_email)]

hospital_serializer = HospitalsSerializer(hospitals, many=True)
```

Any suggestions would help thanks in advance.

**Here is the achieved raw query and trying to change this to ORM,**

```
("SELECT * FROM hospitals_hospitals where site_id in (select otl.site_id from otl_otl as otl where salesEmail='{}' GROUP BY otl.site_id)").format(sales_person_email)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont wrap hosptials in a list. Do this instead.

```
hospitals = Hospitals.objects.filter(site_id__in=OTL.objects.filter(salesEmail=sales_person_email).values_list('site_id', flat=True)) 
hospital_serializer = HospitalsSerializer(hospitals, many=True)
```

You can also refer the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-multiple-objects)

Comment: This is just awesome @Abhisek Jebaraj thank you

Comment: Could you please refer me any other documentation as well because I'm totally new for ORM.

Comment: The default docs should more than suffice. The query set API reference also should be good. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/ This is the base for all the ORM queries.

Comment: thanks again @Abhishek Jebaraj